# Modular Spring MVC application

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

I want to develop modular Spring MVC application with core services and utils and modular controllers-services stack.
Which OSGi framework should I use? I found Spring Dynamic Modules, which is well documented, but this is dead project and I didn't find enough references about integration it's successor- Blueprint and Spring.
Or any other?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Dynamic Modules works good especially if you use Spring in general.

The Spring DM project moved to the Eclipse Fundation and is now called Eclipse Gemini Blueprint.